Can a SOCKS5 Proxy be Integrated with asyncpg for PostgreSQL Connections?
I'm currently utilizing asyncpg for managing connections to PostgreSQL databases. I'm interested in incorporating a SOCKS5 proxy into this setup. Does asyncpg support the use of SOCKS5 proxies for database connections? If so, how can this be implemented?
